# questions about react controlled text field?

Tags: reactjs

You can see below sample code, it's a typical controlled field.

```
export default class NameForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: ''};
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form>
        <label>
          Name:
          <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

I can understand that if I type any text in the field, the value will be reflected into the text field due to the **setState** function and the **value** props of the input.

But if I changed the input to below. I removed the **value** props.

```
<input type="text" onChange={this.handleChange} />
```

Currently, If I typed any value in the field, the value will be still there, but as per my knowledge of **React**, the input will be rendered after the **setState**, but the props **value** is not set, the input will be cleared in my opinion, Could you please explain it in detail for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you miss the important point here. After `setState` is called the component render will be called - but this will not recreate the input component from scratch. Internally react will check and apply only changes that has happened to the actual DOM.

In your case no differences to the input were made - therefore it will stay as it is.

This process is called `reconciliation` and you can read more about it [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reconciliation.html).

Answer (score 1):

Setting value on an input element makes it a controlled input. Controlled inputs always show the value provided in their prop. For example if you have this input:

`<input value='constant' onChange={({target: {value}}) => this.setState({value})}/>`

User can't change its value. but if you don't provide value prop for your input it's not a controlled value and it shows the value user enters in. This same thing is true for checkboxes, radio buttons, etc.

So in your case it updates based on user input because it's not a controlled component (because you didn't provide value for it.)
If you want to set initial value for a component but keep it uncontrolled (user can change the value of component) you can set the initial value with `defaultValue` prop.

You can read more here:
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be setting the `value`, just the `defaultValue`, like this

```
<input type="text" defaultValue={this.state.value}
```

The handleChange will then make sure the state is updated